# Kohana 3.1 country validation callback

Tags: validation, callback, kohana

I'm trying to setup the registration function on my site and I need to validate user's input of country of select type:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            ......
            'country' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('digit'),
                array(array($this, 'country_from_list'), array(':validation', ':field'))
            ),
            ......
        );
    }
```

and here is my callback:

```
public static function country_from_list($values)
{
    // array id => value
    $countries = ORM::factory('country')->getActive('array');

    return Validation::factory($values)
        ->rule('country', 'in_array', array(':value', $countries));
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas? I'm trying to port it from Kohana 3.0.9...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're passing the Validation object to the callback method, you can do a custom error on it if it fails your condition. (inside of your callback: $validation->error(...))

Otherwise, your callback should accept the field's value, return bool and look like this :

```
// The callback method is static, you shouldn't call it on the instance.
array(array('Model_Whatever::country_from_list'), array(':value'))
```

And the method:

```
public static function country_from_list($value)
{
    return in_array($value, ORM::factory('country')->getActive('array'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue (at least). The following:

```
array(':value', $countries)
```

is actually an array, where:

- first element is `:value` string,
- second element is the result of `ORM::factory('country')->getActive('array')`,

But I am not an expert in Kohana 3.1's validation - I heard it has changed since 3.0.